# Postgresql store RSA public key

Tags: java, postgresql, numbers, rsa, modulus

I would like to store RSA modulus's in a Postgresql database. The problem is that a modules is way to long to be stored as a number... Is there a better way to store RSA public keys?

The only thing I use it for is comparing 2 `PublicKey`'s I thought it would be very easy to compare the modules from the database and the `PublicKey.getModules()`. Or is storing the public key as a number just stupid...

Comment: What language please?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Java